# Why I can print the first element in an empty list?

Tags: c++, containers

Spend the whole afternoon to debug one issue. Completely confused on why I can print the first element from an empty list. It seems this is C++ issue or my program issue. It seems C++ randomly point to local address when I try to access the first element

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
         string crc_command = "ls /tmp/jacknotexist";
         list<string> crc_output;
         printf("list begin:%s\n", (*(crc_output.begin())).c_str()); // The result is "ls /tmp/jacknotexist". Why???
         printf("list size:%d\n", crc_output.size()); // It is zero as expected.
}
```

Comment: Because C++ doesn't hold your hand and tell you off if you don't follow its rules. You don't pay for what you don't use.

Comment: to be honest I get a segmentation fault.. anyway chris is right: accessing out-of-bounds memory is undefined behavior. The standard pattern is to check the bounds and **then** read

Comment: By the way, using `printf` to print the result of `size()` is unsafe. There's a good chance that `%zu` is the right format specifier, but you can't be sure.

Comment: that's the real difference between `[]` and the member function `at()` when dealing with vectors, here the principle is the same, C++ gives you the tools, you are supposed to know better about how things work or should work in memory.

Comment: In C++ I would use std::cout

Comment: How do you print an element from an empty list. It`s just empty and there is no element to print, because the list basically contains a null reference. Unless you add the string "crc_command" to the list then your list will contain a null reference.

Comment: A good compiler in debug mode should generate an error for you, although it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 3):

> The result is "ls /tmp/jacknotexist". Why???

Actually, the result is undefined behavior: even though the list is empty, its `begin()` function returns some value (which happens to be equal to the value returned by `end()` function). When you dereference that iterator, it again produces some value. At this point, the behavior is undefined, and a program could crash on any other platform.

Essentially this is the same sort of behavior that one gets when dereferencing an invalid pointer: the program may or may not crash, and it may produce any value at all. In your case, the invalid value happens to coincide with the content of `crc_command` variable.